# example of smoothing of quotient surface singularities with maximal Milnor number

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

In Wahl's paper "Smoothing of normal surface singularities", he shows that smoothing in the Artin component of a quotient surface singularity has the maximal Milnor number in the versal family. However, is there any example that a smoothing in a non-Artin component has the same Milnor number as that of the Artin component?